# Mail.app and gmail spam

Tags: macos, gmail, apple-mail, spam-prevention

gmail's spam filter learns very quickly and marks messages as spam even after just once or twice that I marked messages from a certain sender as such.

Since I use Mail.app with POP to fetch gmail, whenever I want to mark a message as spam I need to switch over to the web interface, find that message, and mark. Very tedious, plus doesn't work if I'm offline obviously...

Is there any way I could bridge over so that when I mark a message in Mail.app it automatically signals to gmail (according to a message-id or what not) that this message should be marked as spam? Any solution, including those involving a combination of applescript, web service, etc would be welcome.

Comment: Why don't you use IMAP? I guess that way, Mail can be configured to use Gmail's existing *Spam* folder instead of the local *Junk* one.

Comment: IMAP has too many downsides for me to use it over POP

Comment: I'm curious, what downsides does IMAP have that you're trying to avoid? I think IMAP is generally considered the superior protocol.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to IMAP you can mark messages as spam by moving them to the [Gmail]/Spam folder. Similarly moving them away from the spam folder will tell Gmail that the message was not spam.